# min and max in certain lines of input file with the tag of line number

Tags: linux, tags, line, max

I want to find the minimum between the line number 2000 and 3000.

I want to find the minimum and maximum of the values and when the minimum and maximum are found , I also need to find the line on which it was found.
Then I want to go to one line above the maximum or minimum containing line and output the 
first integer out of the 6 integers on the same line.

My input is of the following form.

```
*KEYWORD
$TIME_VALUE = 1.4000002e+001
$STATE_NO = 15
$Output for State 15 at time = 14
*ELEMENT_SHELL_THICKNESS
1346995      25 1457683 1471891 1457727 1471929
9.953265e-001   9.953265e-001   9.953265e-001   9.953265e-001
1346996      25 1471891 1457685 1471930 1457727
9.953963e-001   9.953963e-001   9.953963e-001   9.953963e-001
1346997      25 1457685 1471892 1471931 1471930
9.953437e-001   9.953437e-001   9.953437e-001   9.953437e-001
```

so output could be

```
min=9.953265e-001  on line  07   at  1346995
max=9.953963e-001  on line  09   at  1346996
```

PS:  I can find the min and maximum of an array but to tackle this input is hard for me.
waiting for expert suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dot not understand the requirement between line number 2000 and 3000, but if it is in your example between line number 6 and 11:

```
cat your_file | awk '
  NR >= 6 && NR <= 11{at=$1;getline
    if (max < $1){max=$1;max_line=NR;max_at=at}
    if (min > $1){min=$1;min_line=NR;min_at=at}}
  NR == 7{min=$1;min_line=NR;min_at=at}
  END{
    printf "min=%-13e on line  %02d at %8d\n", min, min_line, min_at
    printf "max=%-13e on line  %02d at %8d\n", max, max_line, max_at}'
```

And would the max not be on line 9 ?

(To all, please do not useless use of cat me, I find it clearer this way ;-).)

Comment: yes , you are right , it should be on line 9, however the lines 2000 and 3000 are in my code so I wanted a generalized answer, which you have already given.. I really appreciate the wonderful support of you guys.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/851677/jfgagne    I am obliged for the support bestowed upon me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/851677/jfgagne                          can you please explain why have you used NR instead of FNR? If I am writing a script , isn't it better to use FNR?  so that in a  shell where different files are being edited , there is not chance of error?   what do u say?

Comment: I say that it is not important in this case: both have the same result.  In the general case, there is no better way, only the ones that result in the solution that fits you.  As you seam to have understand the difference between NR and FNR, I think you will be able to choose the one that fits what you want to achieve.