# finding min and maximum between two strings in a data file using linux

Tags: linux, string, max, minimum

```
*KEYWORD
$TIME_VALUE = 1.4000002e+001
$STATE_NO = 15
$Output for State 15 at time = 14
*ELEMENT_SHELL_THICKNESS
1346995      25 1457683 1471891 1457727 1471929
9.953265e-001   9.953265e-001   9.953265e-001   9.953265e-001
1346996      25 1471891 1457685 1471930 1457727  
9.953963e-001   9.953963e-001   9.953963e-001   9.953963e-001
1346997      25 1457685 1471892 1471931 1471930
9.953437e-001   9.953437e-001   9.953437e-001   9.953437e-001
*End
```

so output could be

```
min=9.953265e-001  on line  07   at  1346995
max=9.953963e-001  on line  09   at  1346996
```

A probable solution , if we know the line numbers is

```
cat your_file | awk '
NR >= 6 && NR <= 11{at=$1;getline
if (max < $1){max=$1;max_line=NR;max_at=at}
if (min > $1){min=$1;min_line=NR;min_at=at}}
NR == 7{min=$1;min_line=NR;min_at=at}
END{
printf "min=%-13e on line  %02d at %8d\n", min, min_line, min_at
printf "max=%-13e on line  %02d at %8d\n", max, max_line, max_at}'
```

but what if I want to search between *Keyword and *End , because due to a small editing in the file the string comes to the defined lines and its values is 0 so the minimum is set to zero.

Any suggestion.

I must mention that this good solution was provided by [jfgagne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851677/jfgagne) in my previous question: [min and max in certain lines of input file with the tag of line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262454/min-and-max-in-certain-lines-of-input-file-with-the-tag-of-line-number).

Comment: what do u think, if I first of all find the NR on which the first string exist and then the NR where the second string exist and then follow the same code?   can you please suggest to find the NR on which the specific string exist? I have an idea of doing it in this way, may be novice but I think it will work for sure.

Comment: You could do that as well, but it requires two passes over the file.  If it's not a large file, do whatever feels the most comfortable. Or you could split this into two scripts; one which prints the desired region only, and the other to do what you are doing now.  Hint: `sed  -n '/^\*ELEMENT_SHELL_THICKNESS$/,/^\*End$/p' your_file | awk ...`  But it's not hard to do the state variable thing, either.  (Moved my comment into an answer and provided code to implement it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a state to your script. If your state variable is false; set it to true if you are looking at the start marker; in any event, skip to next line.  If your state variable is true; if looking at end marker, set the state variable to false, and skip to the next line; otherwise, you are in the region; process the line as before.

```
awk '!there{if($1 == "*ELEMENT_SHELL_THICKNESS") there=1; next}
there&&/^\*End$/{there=0;next}
{at=$1;getline
  if (!max || max < $1){max=$1;max_line=NR;max_at=at}
  if (!min || min > $1){min=$1;min_line=NR;min_at=at}}
END{
  printf "min=%-13e on line  %02d at %8d\n", min, min_line, min_at
  printf "max=%-13e on line  %02d at %8d\n", max, max_line, max_at}' your_file
```

I assume the start marker is `*ELEMENT_SHELL_THICKNESS` as suggested by the code, rather than `*KEYWORD` as you say in the question.  I removed the `min` and `max` initialization code, mostly out of laziness; if either can be zero, perhaps you should put it back in.

This also does away with the Useless Use of Cat.  http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html